# Running ng build generates error for AnimationEntryMetadata

Tags: angular

I get this error when running ng build:

> ERROR in node_modules/@wheels/framework/dist/lib/app/wh-core/utilities/animation-utils.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/lthurman/Documents/angular-projects/ui/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'AnimationEntryMetadata'.

npm 5.6.0
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.6

I've seen posts on similar errors, but no resolution for my particular issue.
Any ideas?

Comment: wrong import. means you should import that class from another file. or that class is meant to be used internally by that library you are using. I dont know the exact case but that should be similar to what i said

Comment: can you show us what code you used for importing that library?